# Android programmatically get data usage for specific app, for example: Data Usage used on "Facebook"

Tags: java, android, network-traffic

I would like to categorize the data usage by:

```
OS ------60% (300MB used so far)
Music ------ 10% (50MB used so far)
Facebook -----5% (25MB used so far)
```

Anyone can help me in solving this Android programming as I am a beginner of Android development and would like to develop a mobile network monitor app currently.
I would like to get the data usage by specifying the app name.

Thank you. Hope to hear from you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html#getUidRxBytes(int)

> public static long getUidRxBytes (int uid)
>
> Added in API level 8 Return number of bytes received by the given UID
>   since device boot. Counts packets across all network interfaces, and
>   always increases monotonically since device boot. Statistics are
>   measured at the network layer, so they include both TCP and UDP usage.
>
> Before JELLY_BEAN_MR2, this may return UNSUPPORTED on devices where
>   statistics aren't available.
>
> See Also myUid() uid

and

> public static long getUidTxBytes (int uid)
>
> Added in API level 8 Return number of bytes transmitted by the given
>   UID since device boot. Counts packets across all network interfaces,
>   and always increases monotonically since device boot. Statistics are
>   measured at the network layer, so they include both TCP and UDP usage.
>
> Before JELLY_BEAN_MR2, this may return UNSUPPORTED on devices where
>   statistics aren't available.
>
> See Also myUid() uid

Comment: any way to get the total traffic since the beginning? I see that these return only the traffic since boot.